# How to get average of likes per member of a social network website

Tags: sql, oracle, average

So I have 3 tables:

```
Member (
  memberId integer,
  name varchar(50)
)

Photo (
  memberId integer,
  photoId integer
)

Like (
  photoId integer,
  memberId integer 
)
```

I need to get, for each member, the average of likes that he has across all of his photos.
I'm able to do it if every photos has at least one like, but if I add a photo without any likes, it does not get include in the result...

Thank you for your help

edit: 
Here's what I did earlier for the memberId 201701

```
SELECT AVG(RCOUNT) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT (*) AS RCOUNT 
    FROM LIKE 
    WHERE photoId IN 
    (
        SELECT photoId 
        FROM PHOTO 
        WHERE memberId = 201701
    ) 
    GROUP BY photoId 
);
```

Comment: Please post the query you tried with.

Comment: I added it in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with an outer join between the tables `LIKE` and `PHOTO`

```
SELECT AVG(RCOUNT) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT (*) AS RCOUNT 
    FROM PHOTO as AS p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LIKE as l on p.photoId = l.photoId
   WHERE p.memberId = 201701
   GROUP BY p.photoId );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a join  of the finner subquery  ( with left join for photo without like)

```
SELECT AVG(T.RCOUNT) 
FROM 
(
        SELECT nvl(count( * ),0) as  RCOUNT 
        FROM PHOTO  as  a
        left  JOINN LIKE as b on a.a.photoId  = b.photoId 
        WHERE a.memberId = 201701
        group by a.photoId

) T
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking wrong question.

1. If you want to get average of count of Photo which is in Like table, you have to query only Like table as you did.
2. If you want to get average of count of Photo which is in Like table or not in Like table, you don't have to query Like table, because Photo table has all PhotoId including Like table.

So, previous answer like following:

```
SELECT AVG(RCOUNT) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT (*) AS RCOUNT 
        FROM PHOTO as AS p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LIKE as l on p.photoId = l.photoId
    WHERE p.memberId = 201701
GROUP BY p.photoId );
```

can be converted like following:

```
SELECT AVG(RCOUNT) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT (*) AS RCOUNT 
        FROM PHOTO as AS p
    WHERE p.memberId = 201701
    GROUP BY p.photoId );
```

These two querys return exactly same result, since first query uses outer join.